# SQL query (AND & OR) mix up

Tags: mysql, sql

help me understand why i am getting different COUNTS

Query 1

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   `foo` 
WHERE  `status_id` = 2 
       AND `updated_at` < Date(Now() - INTERVAL 1 day) 
       AND `number` LIKE 'A390%' 
        OR `number` LIKE 'A391%' 
        OR `number` LIKE 'A392%'
```

> results = 20000

Query 2

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   `foo` 
WHERE  `status_id` = 2 
       AND `updated_at` < Date(Now() - INTERVAL 1 day) 
       AND ( `number` LIKE 'A390%' 
              OR `number` LIKE 'A391%' 
              OR `number` LIKE 'A392%' )
```

> results = 14967

---

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   `foo` 
WHERE  `status_id` = 2 
       AND `updated_at` < Date(Now() - INTERVAL 1 day) 
       AND `number` LIKE X
```

running the above query for each (A390, A391 ,A392) separately gives me:

> ```
> 'A390%' = 0; 
> 'A391%' = 1496; 
> 'A392%' = 10000;
> ```

EDIT:
Adding Screenshots to make it more clear. i had to do some photoshop to change the table name

[image: Query 1]

[image: Query 2]

[image: Query 3]

[image: Query 4]

[image: Query 5]

Comment: There is no reason for the total from the three individual queries to be less than the result of the second query.  Looking at the numbers, I suspect you mistyped something.

Comment: second and third cant be different

Comment: I will double check all my numbers

Comment: If a typo in the third is not the cause, are you sure the data is not being changed elsewhere? In theory, `updated_at < Date(Now() - INTERVAL 1 day)` may result in higher counts if run later; but only data changes (or typos) should result in lower ones.

Comment: Regarding the screenshots added, the total of the third query's execution is the same as the second one's; the answers posted so far explain why the first query differs from those.

Comment: yes u are right. i ran a query where  `number` LIKE 'A391%' 
 OR `number` LIKE 'A392%' and the total came out to be 20k. so you are correct. thank you for your help.

Comment: 20k results sounds like a suspiciously round number, there is probably a default/hidden limit on the querying platform you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html

Your first query's condition is equivalent to:

```
 (`status_id` = 2 
   AND `updated_at` < Date(Now() - INTERVAL 1 day) 
   AND `number` LIKE 'A390%'
 )
 OR `number` LIKE 'A391%' 
 OR `number` LIKE 'A392%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` operator has higher precedence than `OR`, so your first query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   `foo` 
WHERE
     (`status_id` = 2 
       AND `updated_at` < Date(Now() - INTERVAL 1 day) 
       AND `number` LIKE 'A390%') 
     OR `number` LIKE 'A391%' 
     OR `number` LIKE 'A392%'
```

In contrast with your second query, the conditions on `status_id` and `updated_at` apply only to the rows where `number LIKE 'A390%'`.

The total count over the three individual queries cannot be less than the count returned by the second query, if all queries are performed on the same data.  Presumably you have made a typo somewhere.  The total of the individual queries could be *greater*, however, if any rows' `number`s satisfy more than one of the `LIKE` conditions.

Comment: There is no typo, i added screenshots.

Comment: @M.ofCA, maybe my eyes are going bad, but I ***swear*** your last three screenshots show your individual query results to be 0, 4967, and 10000, respectively.  The sum of those is 14967, which is exactly the count you get from your second full query.  The result of the second individual query differs from the result you claim in the question text (or so my possibly-failing eyes tell me).  Are you still telling me there's no typo?